# In a SMS only display a variable if under a certain lenght

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobile, mobileconnect, sms

I wanted to send a SMS and only display the "FirstName" of the recipient if this variable is under a certain character length.

I was looking at how to do this and can see two options:

Length

```
%%[IF (Length(@FirstName)>8 THEN]%%
```

Hi, etc etc

```
%%[ELSEIF (Length(@FirstName)<8 THEN]%%
```

Hi %%FirstName%%, etc etc

or I could use Substring

```
%%=Substring("FirstName",1,8)=%%
```

I've searched quite extensively on here and couldn't find a question that covers this.

Is this the correct method to use or is there another way that's considered best practise?

Comment: What app are you using for the sending of the SMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to use [AttributeValue](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/attributevalue/#attributevalue) AmpScript function to check `FirstName` field value.

```
%%[ 
SET @Firstname = AttributeValue("FirstName")
    IF Not Empty(@Firstname) Then
        IF Length(@Firstname) > 8 Then
                SET @Name = "Dear Customer"
        Else
                SET @Name = ConCat('Dear',' ',@Firstname)
        ENDIF
    Else
        SET @Name = "Dear Customer"
    EndIf
]%%

%%=v(@Name)=%%
```

Comment: AttributeValue() FTW!

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this

```
%%[ 
SET @Firstname = FirstName
  IF Length(@Firstname) > 8 Then
    SET @Name = "Dear Customer"
  ELSE 
    SET @Name = Concat('Dear', @Firstname)
  ENDIF
]%%
%%=v(@Name)=%%
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
%%[
var @message, @name
set @name = FirstName

IF Length(@name) < 8 AND Length(@name) > 0  THEN
set @message = concat(Hi, @name)
ELSE THEN
set @message = "Hi customer!"
ENDIF
]%%

%%=v(@message)=%%
```

Comment: This is close, but I would be careful with length > 0 as this won't catch true null or empty values every time.

Comment: @Gortonington  Thanks I've noticed that occurring for a lot of my dynamic emails how do you get around it if you actually need to do a value of > 0

I.E you want to display if it's under 1

I guess you could do something like != 1 or > 0.5 right?

Comment: You can do something like IF NOT EMPTY(@var) AND LENGTH(@var) > 0. This will allow the option to set an else for null or empty variables.    There are quite a few options, if you open a question with your specific needs, we may be able to help more

Comment: @Gortonington Okay excellent thanks for your response. Very nice to know. I'll open another if I run into any issues.

Answer (score 0):

[@Palash Rai](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/20977/palash-rai) is 100% right - especially about the AttributeValue love. I just would slightly adjust his code to make it more efficient by removing the need for a double IF ELSE statements.

```
%%[
VAR @Firstname, @Name

SET @Firstname = AttributeValue("FirstName")
SET @Name = "Dear Customer"

IF NOT EMPTY(@FirstName) AND Length(Firstname) > 8 THEN
  SET @Name = CONCAT('Dear ', Firstname)
ENDIF
]%%
```

This will make sure a default is always set for @Name prior to any conditional processing and would reduce the overall processing and physical code needed.